# How to loop over a list of object in JSTL

Tags: java, spring, loops, jsp, web

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8MtZ.png)I have the following list which is coming from a class via toString method .
I am passing the list in modelAndView object to jsp page.
Now I want to loop over the list and make a table in jsp Page.
Please guide.

```
 List<LocationStats> allStates = [LocationStats{state='Fujian', country='Afghanistan', latestTotalCases=51526}, LocationStats{state='Guangdong', country='Albania', latestTotalCases=59438}] ;
```

//////////////////////////   LocationStats.JAVA  ///////////////////////////////////////

```
public class LocationStats {
    
    private String state;
    private String country;
    private int latestTotalCases;
    
    
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public  void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    public int getLatestTotalCases() {
        return latestTotalCases;
    }
    public void setLatestTotalCases(int latestTotalCases) {
        this.latestTotalCases = latestTotalCases;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "LocationStats{" +
                "state='" + state + '\'' +
                ", country='" + country + '\'' +
                ", latestTotalCases=" + latestTotalCases +
                '}';
    }
    
}
```

/////////////////////////////   HomeController.java  ////////////////////////

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public ModelAndView home() {    
    
    
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.addObject("location", coronaVirusDataService.getAllStates());
    mv.setViewName("home.jsp");
    return (mv);        
}
```

///////////////////  home.jsp   //////////////////////

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>state</th>
    <th>country</th>
    <th>latestTotalCases</th>
  </tr>
   <tr th:each="elements : ${location}">
    <td th:text="${elements.state}"></td>
    <td th:text="${elements.country}"></td>
    <td th:text="${elements.latestTotalCases}">0</td>
  </tr>             
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>state</th>
    <th>country</th>
    <th>latestTotalCases</th>
  </tr>
  <c:forEach items="${location}" var="element"> 
    <tr>
      <td>${element.state}</td>
      <td>${element.country}</td>
      <td>${element.latestTotalCases}</td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, this is just showing a blank page with just only the table headings

Comment: Hmm, what version of Servlets are you using? It's possible the Servlets isn't playing nice with your Server.

Example: http://java-with-shiva.blogspot.com/2013/07/spring-jstl-variable-does-not-display.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, the code is working now. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should add `taglib` at the beginning of `jsp` file.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Than you can write it in this way:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>state</th>
    <th>country</th>
    <th>latestTotalCases</th>
  </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${location}" var="elements">
        <tr>
            <td>${elements.state}</td>
            <td>${elements.country}</td>
            <td>${elements.latestTotalCases}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>             
</table>
```

You can also check if this 'location' is not empty, for example by printing it out:

```
<%=location%>
```

Comment: i have added the core tag library and since I am using maven so added the dependencies as well in pom file but I am not getting the output on jsp. although i have tested the data flow  of "${location}" is smooth uptill jsp page but while trying to print it in a table format i don't get any data except table header (the hardcoded once).
pls suggest.

Comment: Thank you so much, it solved the problem. You made my day :)

Comment: @AATIFKHAN 
so you can vote for the answer

Comment: I am not qualified to vote yet coz my reputation points are less. sorry

Comment: @AATIFKHAN you can start participate in Stack. For example by accepting answers or do simple edit in others answers (just formatting the code). I voted for your question to give you some point for the start.